# Inherit be_acl pages permissions on complex TYPO3 installations

Tags: acl, typo3, user-permissions

TYPO3's extension [be_acl](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/be_acl/current) helps to manage permissions on pages on complex installations, when multiple groups works together.

Just there is some kind of bug : when a user creates a page, permissions of page-parent are not inherited, and we should resolve the conflict manually.

Ex. :

- page parent number 1 is assigned to two user groups A and B
- a user from A group creates a subpage 2 under 1
- a user from B group couldn't edit page 2, as the permissions from page 1 were not inherited, and default permissions for others is only "read"

Such conflicts provokes bugs for further BE user's collaboration, the admin should resolve conflicts manually.

Does anybody had such type of permissions conflicts and managed to resolve such issue ?

Comment: This should work as long as you set the permissions on the page 1 to be recursive. If you are truly setting the recursive parameter on the permissions, check if the problem persists when the user from group B logs off and on again. If it does, there is some problem I haven't experienced. If it does not, it might be one of the bugs that there used to be/are in be_acl after the caching was introduced in it in some version.

Comment: @cascaval Thank You very much, effectively, I applied modifications from the forge of be_acl, which contains cache tuning, and it resolves the issue. Except this, I changed default owner of root page to admin, and moved additional groups into be_acl space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cascaval answer in question's comments helped to manage the issue.

Key elements :

- Latest version of be_acl
- Recursive option is filled in be_acl record
- All groups are defined in be_acl style, and not in traditional TYPO3 maner, to realize heritage on sub-pages